# Macro with calloc, is safe?

Tags: c, dynamic-allocation

is safe if I use this macro in my code?

```
#define my_calloc(x, n) ((x) = (__typeof__ (x))calloc((n), sizeof(__typeof__ (&(x)))))
```

I'm usign gcc as compiler...

In my programm there is a lot of memory allocation point, so I use this.
I tried it 5 minutes ago and I get some weird sigabort and sigsev, now I'm going home... after I'll try again if I can find something.

Some idea/tip?

EDIT ADDED:

Generally I use the macro as follows:

```
double *x;
my_calloc(x, 10);

int **y;
my_calloc(y, 30);
```

Comment: Note that it's unnecessary and potentially dangerous to cast the result of malloc/calloc in C.

Comment: @Paul R: Is there any danger if you are compiling in C99, where there must be a declaration of `malloc()` in scope before it is used?

Comment: @Jonathan: you may be right - I can't think of a dangerous scenario when prototypes are mandatory. Even if we can assume C99 though, I never like to see unnecessary type casts - it's a "code smell".

Comment: C99 does not mandate prototypes: `int main(void) { return abs(0); }` is a strictly conforming program.

Comment: @pmg: You are relying on an implicit declaration of `abs()` as a function returning `int`, and that is not permitted in strict C99.  It would be OK with `extern int abs();` - a non-prototype declaration of the function.  And, more relevantly, '`int main(void) { return malloc(10) != 0; }`' is not strictly conforming (because `malloc()` is not a function that returns an `int`; on M680x0 chips, the return value for `malloc()` should be in register A0, but because the compiler has been lied to, it would look in register D0 for the result, leading to problems!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it should probably be:

```
#define my_calloc(x, n) do { (x) = calloc((n), sizeof *(x)); } while (0)
```

- unnecessary/dangerous cast has been removed
- redundant parentheses removed
- do/while added for correct behaviour between `if (...)` and `else`
- fixed size of type
- remove redundant and non-portable `__typeof__`

Comment: +1, but you removed the *necessary* parentheses around the arguments `(x)` and `(n)` and left the useless ones after `sizeof`... It should read `#define my_calloc(x, n) do { (x) = calloc((n), sizeof *(x)) } while (0)`

Comment: @R. thanks - it's a (possibly bad) habit of mine to always put parentheses after `sizeof`, probably because I can never remember the rule for when they are required and when not. ;-)

Comment: @R.: why does `x` need parentheses ? It can only ever be a variable name, surely ?

Comment: They're only needed for grouping or if you're applying `sizeof` to a parenthesized *type name* and not an expression.

Comment: `x` could be any lvalue of pointer type. Of course if you find that repulsive you could document that `x` must be simply a variable name, but surely someone will want to use it with slightly more complex lvalues like perhaps `*dblptr`.

Comment: @Paul: why the use of a while loop?

Comment: @the_candyman: see answer for explanation - you need do/while (0) for correct behaviour in a situation such as `if (...) my_calloc(x, n); else ...`

Comment: @Paul R, you are missing one of the advantages in your list: avoid useless use of the `__typeof__` extension.

Comment: @Paul: I don't think the `do/while` is strictly necessary here. The `(x) = ...` expression won't confuse an `if` statement (though the expression should be wrapped in parens in that case, as should all macros that evaluate to expressions).  However, I think there's no harm in using the `do/while` wrapper, since `my_calloc()` is unlikely to be used as a sub-expression.

Comment: @Michael: yes, I think you may be right in this instance - I usually take a a defensive approach in these matters - it's safer in general and it also saves me form having to think too much. ;-)

Comment: @Paul: "saves me from having to think too much" - a damn good reason for using an idiom.

Comment: @Paul. I tried the proposed alternative macro, but I get always error... I don't get error if I use the ";"...#define my_calloc(x, n) do { (x) = calloc((n), sizeof *(x)) ; } while (0)

Comment: @the_candyman: sorry about the missing `;` - answer edited to include this now.

Answer (score 4):

Your macro allocates `n` *pointers* not objects.  Try `sizeof(*(x))`.